# Firefox 18.0.1 (Mac) CSS Transition Sequence Jitter

Tags: css, firefox, transition

I'm having issues with jitteriness/ glitchiness in Firefox 18.0.1 when sequencing transitions in CSS using transitionend.  The object I'm trying to animate jumps to the end position briefly, goes back to the start position then proceeds with the tween.

This occurs frequently in Firefox (Mac) and intermittently in Safari. It could also be happening in Windows Firefox, but I haven't checked. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Have a look at the demo here (FYI it's coded specifically for Firefox):
http://umamie.com/csstransition/cssTweenDemo.html

Answer (score 2):

I've been running in to the same issue, so I filed a bug here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=850320

In the mean time, I find queueing a very short delay (10ms or so) between two transitions fixes the jump. If you're using jQuery Transit, just add .delay(10) after any .transition({}) you think will be queued

Comment: I have the same problem on FF22. I think your hack is a bit fragile; In my case a delay of 10 or even 15ms didn't work, but it worked with... 16ms. Transitions/Animations are really not there yet.